# phpstorm accept undefined variables

Tags: php, phpstorm

I'm trying to understand unexpected behavior by PHPstorm. I've two files without any include or required definitions.

`// file1.php 
<?php
      $var = new class1();`

`// file2.php
<?php
      class class1 { }`

I would expect that class1 is undefined in file1, because file2 is not included. But phpstorm shows no warning. CTRL-B jumps to the declaration in file2. The option "Ignore include and require statements" is unchecked. Could someone explain this to me?

Comment: PhpStorm does not really care about include/require statements, especially for classes/interfaces/traits. Class autoloading is normal practice these days: you may have just single require in your whole project (in entry/bootstrap file) and all classes will be loaded automatically (for example, by autoloader generated by Composer). Therefore: it's not a bug at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

phpstorm doesn't know everything about your context. it is possible that the files are required by some other file one after another so everything will just work. Also there is a good chance, that you are using autoloader/composer (who doesn't?) which will take care of the issue.

So, I think they wouldn't consider this an error, as they wouldn't be able to properly filter false-positives if they enabled such warning

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a bug in PHPStorm itself, since PHP throws an exception.

```
Fatal error: Class 'class1' not found in /srv/www/htdocs/swaggityswoogityswoo/f1.php on line 5 Call Stack: 0.0003 629360 1. {main}() /srv/www/htdocs/swaggityswoogityswoo/f1.php:0
```

Since I upgraded to the latest versions, it seems to behave strange. For example, when i try to merge a file where the deployed adn the local file both contain contain 'text-align: left', he wants to merge it into 'text-align: center'.

Just wait until they release another version, maybe they'll be able to fix this bug.

Comment: 1) It's not a bug but the way how IDE works with classes 2) Other issues you have mentioned have nothing to do with the actual question. If you found an issue -- please report to their Issue Tracker at http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI